# PHP database information placed in a table to display on a website

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Hey guys i just want to put the information from the database into a table which i can display on a website but i have no idea how to do it.

```
<?php
include 'database_conn.php';      // make db connection

$sql = "SELECT eventID, eventTitle, eventDescription, venueID, catID, eventStartDate, eventEndDate, eventPrice FROM AE_events ORDER BY eventTitle";
$queryResult = $dbConn->query($sql);
if($queryResult === false) {
echo "<p>Query failed: ".$dbConn->error."</p>\n</sample1>\n</html>";
exit;
}

else {
while($rowObj = $queryResult->fetch_object()){
$eventid = $rowObj->eventID;
$eventT = $rowObj->eventTitle;
$eventDe = $rowObj->eventDescription;
$venueid = $rowObj->venueID;
$catid = $rowObj->catID;
$eventStart = $rowObj->eventStartDate;
$eventEnd = $rowObj->eventEndDate;
$eventPr = $rowObj->eventPrice;


echo "<div class= event>
<span class= title>$eventT</span>
<span class= description>$eventDe</span>
<span class= start_date>$eventStart</span>
<span class= end_date>$eventEnd</span>
£ <span class= price>$eventPr</span> 
</div>";
}
}
$queryResult->close();
$dbConn->close();
?>
```

Comment: *"how can I display this information on my HTML page when I click on the navigation link instead of new page opening"* - I don't see an `href`, or an input or a button of any sorts or anything that shows opening in a new page.

Comment: This is because this is my PHP script I just have the standard HTML navigation script on my HTML file I thought most people know how it looks like so there be no point of posting it.

for example, i know that on my HTML I can just put href  "database.php" but when someone clicks on that link instead of them staying on my website it will open just the information from the database instead of displaying them straight onto the same website in on

Comment: Then wait for someone else to come along, because I don't read invisible code.

Comment: Hey @Fred-ii- go on my website http://unn-w16006107.newnumyspace.co.uk/index.html#

and just click the View events can you see what i mean i want it to display it in like a window on the same page but only display once someone presses that button

Comment: *"i want it to display it in like a window on the same page but only display once someone presses that button"* - you mean an overlay/modal?

Comment: yes i think that will work well but im just not sure how to do it with both HTML file and PHP file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE RIGHT WAY** The key is AJAX. For most uses, the simplest way to do that is generally to add jQuery to your web page and then use a $.ajax() call to call your PHP query and load the results into a  when the user clicks on the link.
There are a bunch of details involved, but spending a little time with a jQuery tutorial should get you going.

**THE LAZY WAY** Preload all the data but hide the window (<div> or <table> or whatever) using CSS and when the user clicks the link just change the CSS on that element to show it, possibly using CSS to hide other parts at the same time to make space. That can be done in pure Javascript easily enough, but even easier with jQuery.